# Filebeat Processor isn't parsing field exception from json log file

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, filebeat

I want to ingest JSON log files from an application into `ElasticSearch`. To do so, I am using `Custom log files` integration running on an `Elastic agent`, that is managed by a `Fleet Manager`.

The log files are composed by a JSON object, one per line, like this:

```
{"timestamp":"2023-08-14T18:00:55.554","level":"ERROR","thread":"http-nio-8080-exec-5","logger":"some class","message":"API error.","context":"default","exception":"some exception message\r\n\t stack..."}
{"timestamp":"2023-08-14T18:00:55.554", ...
```

There are no line breaks or special characters in field as suggested from some posts.

The processor settings defined at for the `agent policy` are these:

```
- decode_json_fields:
    fields: ["message","context"]
    process_array: true
    max_depth: 1
    target: ""
    overwrite_keys: true
    add_error_key: false
```

It works fine, the fields `message`, `context`, `logger`, `timestamp` and so one are all ingested. All but not the `exception` field.

Adding the `exception` field has no effect at all.

I suspect that i need to add the exception field to some schema but i can't figure it out. We are starting now to use Elastic Search and have little knowledge of how it works.

Other thing i suspect is that may be some limit to the size of the field. The exception field is being populated with stack information which can lead to >5k size data. I can't figure it out if there is such a limit.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you set `add_error_key: true` to see if we can get any info from the parsing?

Comment: It has no effect too.

Comment: By manipulating the log file, I was able to import the exception field with a small content size. Clearly a size limit. Just don't know where I can change it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the size of the field exceeded some limit. By setting the processor to truncate the field at 2k max size, the field was properly ingested.

The new configuration:

```
- decode_json_fields:
    fields: ["message","context","exception"]
    process_array: true
    max_depth: 1
    target: ""
    overwrite_keys: true
    add_error_key: false

- truncate_fields:
  fields:
    - exception
  max_characters: 2048
  fail_on_error: false
  ignore_missing: true
```

To avoid losing some important stack data, it is necessary to adjust the way the field is populated. I found out that there are several strategies to work with reduced stack size. One, for example, is reversing the order of the stack so the source should be written first.